# Print javascript array: print A then a1 a2 a3 B then b1 b2 b4 C then c1 c2 c3 (knockout)

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, categories

My question is: how can i print a javascript array with alfabet as category at the beginning? This is what i want:

```
A
 Aapje
 Antje
 Appeltje
B
 Bepje
 Bafke
 Befke
C
 Come
 Cool
 Crap
```

How can i get the printing of array with words get done like this? My array are the words under their respective letters only.

How would I approach this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
<script>var clientSideViewModel = [{"categorie":"Aapje"},{"categorie":"Bapje"},{"categorie":"Capje"},{"categorie":"Dapje"},{"categorie":"Eapje"},
    {"categorie":"Fapje"},{"categorie":"Gapje"},{"categorie":"Hapje"},{"categorie":"Iapje"},
    {"categorie":"Japje"},{"categorie":"Kapje"},{"categorie":"Lapje"},
    {"categorie":"Mapje"},{"categorie":"Napje"},{"categorie":"Oapje"},{"categorie":"Papje"},
    {"categorie":"Qapje"},{"categorie":"Aapje"},{"categorie":"Sapje"},{"categorie":"Tapje"},{"categorie":"Uapje"},{"categorie":"Vapje"}]<?php //echo json_encode($model); ?>; </script>

<h1>Category</h1>
<div class="columns">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: ListOfItems">
        <li data-bind="text: categorie">

    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Using knockout BTW.
ListOfItems = observable array knockout model object.
Im not tied to knockout but it wont hurt to have the solution compatible with it.

Comment: Please provide a sample input

Comment: I dont know what you mean but I added some code.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple vanilla JavaScript:

```
    var model = [{"categorie":"Aapje"},{"categorie":"Bapje"},{"categorie":"Capje"},{"categorie":"Dapje"},{"categorie":"Eapje"},
        {"categorie":"Fapje"},{"categorie":"Gapje"},{"categorie":"Hapje"},{"categorie":"Iapje"},
        {"categorie":"Japje"},{"categorie":"Kapje"},{"categorie":"Lapje"},
        {"categorie":"Mapje"},{"categorie":"Napje"},{"categorie":"Oapje"},{"categorie":"Papje"},
        {"categorie":"Qapje"},{"categorie":"Aapje"},{"categorie":"Sapje"},{"categorie":"Tapje"},{"categorie":"Uapje"},{"categorie":"Vapje"}];

    var map = {};

    model = model.sort(function(a, b){
      return a.categorie > b.categorie ? -1 : 1;
    });

    for (var i=0; i<model.length; i++) {
      var entry = model[i];
      var first = entry.categorie.charAt(0);
      if (!map[first]) {
        map[first] = [];
      }
      map[first].push(entry.categorie);
    }

    console.log('map:', map);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lodash`'s `_.groupBy` method:

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(clientSideViewModel, function (obj) {
    return obj.categorie.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase();
});
```

Check out this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/wofufezuwi/edit?js,console

lodash: https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy